# CSS and text vertical distance spec's

Tags: css

In UI design programs like Sketch, there's always a bounding box around text that seems possibly bigger than what CSS uses in spacing text vertically.

When I'm creating a redline document for front-end developers, which measurement will be the correct one for CSS: the larger bounding box that Sketch shows around text, or the actual exact pixel distance from the top of the capital letter to the object above?

[image: Bounding box]

[image: Actual pixels]

Thanks!

Comment: More info is better.  Personally, I'd like to know the font size and the space(s) required around the font.

Comment: I suppose this was a question relating to any font size. At whatever font size I choose, there's the bounding box in UI design apps, and then there's the reality in CSS--how those pixels are measured. So If I wanted the vertical spacing on a site to exactly match the vertical spacing in a comp, should I provide the developer with the vertical measurement from the top of the bouncing box to the nearest element above, or the exact pixel distance--as those are two different measurements, as I've depicted above. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the larger bounding box - it takes the `line-height` setting into consideration